# foreach in foreach laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I pass two array from controller to view and then i want option to select when the value is the same. But i want to show all data from $arr_1 in select. and my result i get duplicate data in my select.

```
 $arr_1=["1","2","3","4"];
    $arr_2=["1","2","4"];
    @foreach($arr_1 as $val)
       @foreach($arr_2 as $value)
          @if($val==$value)
             <option selected>{{$val}}</option>
          @else
             <option>{{$val}}</option>
          @endif
       @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: Is that a multiselect field?

Comment: check my answer. you are printing or getting in both cases means if condition satisfied or not

Comment: @AdeshKumar what @'s? Did you mean, try to avoid use of laravel to code?

Comment: nope. did my answer not fulfill your needs?

Comment: or you wants all the values of arr_1

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without two foreach

```
$arr_1=["1","2","3","4"];
$arr_2=["1","2","4"];
<select multiple>
    @foreach($arr_1 as $val)
        @if(in_array($val,$arr_2))
         <option val="{{$val}}" selected>{{$val}}</option>
        @else
         <option val="{{$val}}" >{{$val}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/medj-6yxk)